# How to calculate number of bytes sent/received including TCP/IP overhead in an iOS HTTP Connection?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, tcp

I am using NSURLConnection to perform HTTP Communication with a server. I wish to find out the exact number of bytes sent/received by my application including the TCP/IP overhead. 
Haven't found any useful info on how to achieve this after much research.

I am willing to switch to CFStream if using that will help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1. I would be interested in hearing how to do this in _any_ operating system.

Answer (score 4):

In my .h of the controller I declare two vars:

```
NSMutableData *_data;
float downloadSize;
```

Also don't forget the delegates in the .h

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

Then in my .m:

```
- (void)connection: (NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveResponse: (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response
    {
        NSInteger statusCode_ = [response statusCode];
        if (statusCode_ == 200) {
            downloadSize = [response expectedContentLength];
        }
    }
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        if(!_data) _data = [[NSMutableData data]init];
        [_data appendData:data];
        progressView.progress =  ((float) [_data length] / (float) downloadSize);
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
          unsigned char byteBuffer[[_data length]];
          [_data getBytes:byteBuffer];
          [_data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];

    }
```

This is my controller to download a pdf file. But it could be anything really. When it has a response, it gets the expected length, then every time it receives data, it appends it to my mutable data and then compares it to the expected size.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response mashdup. I am using exactly the same thing but unfortunately this does not include the TCP/IP overhead due to multiple frames and the headers byte count. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: no problem dude, you could implement a download class using those methods inside and call its delegates when done etc. They will handle each connection separately. As long you know how big the overheads are, you could offset the expected size in bytes.

Comment: Actually, thats the tricky part. The overhead changes based on the size of data sent. It directly correlates to the number of frames each message is split into. A larger message will be split into a larger number of frames and thus a larger overhead. Also, there seem to be a number of headers that are added at Transport layer but are not available through the Delegates.